# unity - camera movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm reviewing this piece of code about camera movement:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class CamMove : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;
    public float sensitivity=5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    GameObject character;
    void Start()
    {
        //moving left and right
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var md = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse Y")); //mouse movement
        md = Vector2.Scale (md, new Vector2 (sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);



        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);

        mouseLook += smoothV;
        if(mouseLook.y>-40 && mouseLook.y<60)
                    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);

        character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }


 }
```

how does he get every new locatiion ? With Math.Lerp interpolation ? Also I can't understand the part `md = Vector2.Scale (md, new Vector2 (sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));`
Also the part :

```
if(mouseLook.y>-40 && mouseLook.y<60)
                    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
```

Comment: When in doubt, follow the code.. if you dont understand what it does, look up the unity calls, print out the values... and watch and see what happens

Comment: All the code does is move the camera left and right when called using the mouse position.  It is only looking at the Y range -40 to 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

```
var md = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse Y")); //mouse movement
```

is even commented `mouse movement`. As usual a better variable name would already explain it. It would be better called `mouseDelta`. So the code not using a fixed mouse position but rather the traveled dinstance since last frame. (See [Input.GetRawAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html))

---

Then

```
md = Vector2.Scale (md, new Vector2 (sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
```

[`Vector2.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Scale.html) is scaling up or down this Vector. You could also write it as

```
md = new Vector2 (md.x * sensitivity * smoothing, md.y * sensitivity * smoothing);
```

Actually it is quite unnecessary because you could write it way simplier like this:

```
md *= sensitivity * smoothing;
```

---

Then [`Mathf.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) is a linear interpolation between the two given positions using a certain `factor` between `0` and `1`, where `0` would be fully the first parameter, `1` fully the second, otherwise anything in between. E.g. a factor `0.5` would result in the center between both values so this depends on your given value for `smoothing`

```
    smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
    smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
```

Again this is written quite unnecessarily because it is better written directly using [`Vector2.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html)

```
 smoothV = Vector2.Lerp(smoothV, md, 1f/smoothing);
```

But actually I'm not quite sure this even does what you would expect since this is no absolute value but something you later on **add** every frame so using a `Lerp` on it makes not much sense to me anyway... I would probably directly use `Lerp` for moving the current `mouseLoock` towards the new target value.

---

Finally you do

```
mouseLook += smoothV;
if(mouseLook.y>-40 && mouseLook.y<60)
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);

character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
```

Which updates two **rotations**. There is nothing in your code assigning any new **position** at all ...

---

Besides that the frame wise usage of `GetComponent` is extremely inefficient, you should rather store that reference **once** (e.g. in `Start`) and reuse it later.